# Problem with Server Side Validation Control in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I have an problem with Validation in .NET

I am using server side validation for a text box, i applied requiredfield and range validator for that. and my issue is i want to display messages in same place instead of using 
 for both the messages.
suppose i left the textbox it says "it is required" and if i enter some value beyond the range it says "Range must be 1 to 100" but both the messages are in different places which doesn't seems good.

i don't want to use validation summary, i tried "validationGroup" and "Display" property, but i still didn't get the solution.

can anyone have any idea?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpID" runat="server" CssClass ="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtEmpID" ErrorMessage="Emp ID is Must" 
                Display ="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtEmpID" ErrorMessage="Range must be 1 -100" 
                MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer" Display ="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CustomValidator and validate it manually. You will have the message in one place and one validation. The other solution is to have only RangeValidator and enable it even if the TextBox value is empty. ValidateOnEmpty="true" if i'm not wrong

Comment: i never used CustomValidator before, but i am trying now. do you have any sample or good link ?

Comment: Have a read @ http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/ and http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx

Comment: Sorry. Yea RangeValidator doesn't have ValidateOnEmpty. You can try Regex Validator though

Answer (score 1):

You now have a hardcoded `<br />` between the two validators. Remove that (and maybe add that to the ErrorMessage of the first validator: `ErrorMessage="Emp ID is Must<br />"`).

You already have the `Display=Dynamic` so that a non-firing validator doesn't take up space.

Comment: @subeer: exactly what 'is not working'? What do you see, what do you want to see?

Answer (score -1):

ysrb is right, you only want the RangeValidator because the message "Range must be 1 -100" is applicable even if the text box is left empty

Comment: No, the range validator doesn't fire for empty textboxes.